# Was sind die Bedeutungsunterschiede der Begriffe "Steuer", "Gebühr" und "Abgabe"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

Was sind die Unterschiede zwischen diesen Begriffen?

- Steuern
- Gebühren
- Abgaben

Da ich in einen Job gelandet bin, in dem es um Zoll und Zahlungen in Bezug auf Zoll geht, muss ich mir da sicher sein, welchen Begriff ich verwenden soll.

Zusätzlich möchte ich gern wissen, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen *Zollgebühren* und *Zollabgaben* gibt.

Comment: Willkommen! Eine der Anforderungen, die wir bei Fragen dieser Art (ok, eigentlich bei allen) stellen ist in der Frage auch anzugeben, was die eigene Recherche ergeben hat. Falls Du die juristische Definition brauchst, wäre die Antwort eines *Juristen* evtl. belastbarer als die eines *Linguisten*.

Comment: Ich rate dringend an, ein Lehrbuch für öffentliches Recht zu konsultieren. Dies ist meines Wissens eine der Standardfragen in Prüfungen für alle Verwaltungsberufe.

Answer (score 1):

[Steuern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steuer):

> Als Steuer (früher auch Taxe) wird eine Geldleistung ohne Anspruch auf individuelle Gegenleistung bezeichnet, die ein öffentlich-rechtliches Gemeinwesen zur Erzielung von Einnahmen allen steuerpflichtigen Personen – was sowohl natürliche als auch juristische Personen einschließt – auferlegt.

[Gebühren](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geb%C3%BChr):

> Eine Gebühr ist das von einem Wirtschaftssubjekt zu zahlende Entgelt für eine in Anspruch genommene Dienstleistung.

[Abgaben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abgabe):

> Als Abgaben sind materielle Aufwendungen – insbesondere Steuern – zu verstehen, die zu Abgabeleistungen verpflichtete Personen an empfangsberechtigte Personen oder Institutionen abzuführen haben.

Answer (score 0):

Mit welchen Bedeutungen diese Begriffe im Alltags-Deutsch beladen sind, kann sich ziemlich drastisch von den Bedeutungen unterscheiden, die diese Begriffe in der Amtssprache haben. Insbesondere haben solche Begriffe typischerweise in unterschiedlichen Ländern (z.B. Deutschland, Österreich, Schweiz) auch unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Das kann sogar von Kanton zu Kanton oder von Bundesland zu Bundesland unterschiedlich sein.

Ich kenne leider keine Bespiele aus dem Umfeld deiner Begriffe, aber ich weiß, dass es z.B. in Österreich kein *Bußgeld* gibt, weil dieses Wort in keinem österreichischen Gesetz vorkommt. Bei uns heißt das "Geldstrafe", und zur Zahlung einer solche Geldstrafe wird man in Österreich durch eine Organstrafverfügung aufgefordert, welches es wiederum in Deutschland nicht gibt.

Der Grund dafür ist, dass sich die Behörden an die Definitionen halten müssen, die in den jeweils gültigen Gesetzestexten festgeschrieben sind. Diese Definitionen stammen nicht selten noch aus dem 19. Jahrhundert. Die Alltagssprache kümmert sich aber einen Dreck um solche Gesetzestexte und daher können solche Begriffe mit abweichenden Bedeutungen belegt sein.

Daher mein dringender Rat: Frag deinen Chef oder deine Chefin. Es liegt in deren Verantwortung dich einzuschulen. Dazu musst du nicht das Internet befragen.